# min(count(*)) over... behavior?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand the behavior of

```
select ..... ,MIN(count(*))   over (partition by hotelid)
```

VS

```
select ..... ,count(*)   over (partition by hotelid)
```

Ok.

I have a list of hotels (1,2,3)
Each hotel has departments.
On each departments there are workers.

My Data looks like this :

```
select   *    from data
```

[image]

Ok. Looking at this query :

```
select   hotelid,departmentid  , cnt= count(*)   over (partition by hotelid)
from data
group by hotelid, departmentid
ORDER BY hotelid
```

[image]

I can perfectly understand what's going on here. On that result set, partitioning by `hotelId` , we are **counting** visible rows.

But look what happens with this query :

```
select   hotelid,departmentid  ,  min_cnt = min(count(*))   over (partition by hotelid)   
from data
group by hotelid, departmentid
ORDER BY hotelid
```

[image]

**Question:**
Where are those numbers came from? I don't understand how adding `min` caused that result? `min` of what?
Can someone please explain how's the calculation being made?

[**fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1835c9b857a74f728805d8b924ecc5f4)

Comment: It is very strange... 1 A looks clear = 4 but 3 D should also show 4 as is based in the same number of rows. Anyway, normally OVER() clause is used for the same GROUPING clause that the main SELECT query or when there is no GROUPING clause. It is the first time I see it with different grouping fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 statements are very different. The first query is counting the rows after the grouping and then application the `PARTITION`. So, for example, with hotel `1` there is 1 row returned (as all rows for Hotel `1` have the same department `A` as well) and so the `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY hotelid)` returns 1. Hotel `2`, however, has 2 departments `'B'` and `'C'`, and so hence returns 2.

For your second query, you firstly have the `COUNT(*)`, which is not within the `OVER` clause. That means it counts all the rows within the `GROUP BY` specified in your query: `GROUP BY hotelid, departmentid`. For Hotel `1`, there are 4 rows for department `A`, hence 4. Then you take the minimum of 4; which is unsurprisingly 4. For all the other hotels, they have at least 1 entry with only 1 row for a hotel and department and so returns 1.